# What are good translations for "confidence" and "overconfidence" in terms of abilities/actions?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, synonym

I was discussing descriptive terms for a role playing games rule system in the rpg.SE chat, and we came up with the terms "Confidence" and "Overconfidence" for these artifacts.

I was wondering if there are any other/better translations than

> Selbstbewusstsein

and

> Selbstüberschätzung

that fit with a context where the subject of reference is doing something, for example cracking a computer or fighting an enemy, and the outcome is either positive or not anymore.

If you're interested, the whole discussion can be found here: [rpg.SE chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31291467#31291467)

It doesn't need to be a literal translation, I'd rather look for an analogue.

Answer (score 6):

I think that *Confidence* actually is closer to **Selbstsicherheit** or **Selbstvertrauen**.

Selbst**überschätzung** seems to be the best translation for *Overconfidence*, though.
Unless you want to add an adjective to the others (like *übersteigertes Selbstvertrauen*).

Answer (score 3):

*Selbstbewusstsein* should be replaced by *Selbstvertrauen* (*Selbstbewusstsein* is more of a basic character property; one can have more of less of it but it is  not necessarily related to a specific context), and according to that *übertriebenes* or *übersteigertes Selbstvertrauen* would be my first choice for overconfidence.

Comment: I realise my mistake with that translation. However, an expression like "übertriebenes Selbstvertrauen" is far too long for the use as a rule artifact for an RPG.

Answer (score 2):

Selbstbewusstsein is more like "selfconfidence".

**As a noun:**

confidence: **Selbstvertrauen**, **Selbstsicherheit**

overconfidence: **Hochmut**, **Selbstüberschätzung**

**As an adjectiv:**

in your case confident means **selbstbewusst** or/and **selbstsicher** and

overconfident means **hochmütig** or/and **selbstüberschätzend**.